# Execute a command on a shared gnu-screen (php to garrysmod)?

Tags: php, linux, server, command, gnu-screen

I'm trying to get a website compatible with a screen. I have a Garrysmod game server running on the user garrysmod.
So when I am on the website, I'm on the user www-data, and I need to access the screen "gmod" on user garrysmod.

I have multiuser on, so `screen -x garrysmod/gmod` will attach me to the screen. Although when I try to execute a command, `screen -x garrysmod/gmod -X stuff "hi"` the server receives nothing, but if I do `screen -S garrysmod/gmod -X stuff "hi"` it does not find the screen.
So I have no idea how to send a command from the website, to the screen.

Comment: I tried to use tmux, but that does not have shared sessions.

Comment: tried to start screen on www-data user, worked, but I was not able to start a "script -f" in order to retrieve console feed. So i had no idea what it was doing.

Comment: I have researched on how to execute a php command as a different user (possibly root), but all of them mentioned on how "unsecure" it was, but never went into detail.

Comment: Alight final update, I've made my own program in C. The program does everything I need it too. Did not end up using screen